# ReactJs Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History':

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-navigation

A history state object with URL 'http://components/' cannot be created in a document with origin.
Below is my code. I am trying to achieve this child routes inside my component. I am getting error like above.

```
              <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/rendering`}>Rendering with React</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/components`}>Components</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/props-v-state`}>Props v. State</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/rendering`} component={compo1} />
                <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/components`} component={compo2} />
                <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/sumne`} component={compo3} />
                <Route
                    exact
                    path={this.props.match.url}
                    render={() => <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>}
                />
```

Comment: Please don't put question information in the title. Edit your post, give it a short summary title, and then put the real error, ideally as a stack trace tied to a [mcve] in your post. Having all the details [helps people answer your question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Give me answer of you know

Comment: You are asking normal people for help. Please do not _demand_ that they help you, especially not when they are pointing you to the policy articles that you need to have read as a poster to Stackoverflow. You have 562 rep, so presumably you've read them already: you may want to read them again, because they matter. Please read [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and then update your post.